# Git Diff Indent/Pretty Print/Beautify Before Diff

Tags: c++, git, indentation, pretty-print, git-diff

Is there a way to make Git `indent`/beautify/pretty print two versions of C++ source files before diffing them?

I don't want Git to show me the myriads of changes introduced after someone auto-formatted the code.

Example usage: I hit `git difftool --indent-before-diffing path/to/file` and get the changes after both the original version of `path/to/file` and the modified version of `path/to/file` have been indented.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can find an application that does the indenting for you, you could use the method described [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Binary-Files) for odt files:

> Add the following line to your .gitattributes file:
>
> `*.odt diff=odt`
>
> Now set up the odt diff filter in .git/config:
>
> ```
> [diff "odt"]
>     binary = true
>     textconv = /usr/local/bin/odt-to-txt
> ```

So for C++ files it would be something like this:

```
*.cpp diff=cpp
```

And in the .git/config:

```
[diff "cpp"]
    textconv = /path/to/indenter
```

As pointed out in the comments, [GNU Indent](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) can be used for indenting.

Comment: This is an extremely good answer!! Thanks! It still has the slight downside that I can't easily (i.e. by a command-line switch) turn the feature off. I'll mark this as the correct answer in a few days unless someone comes up with a similar solution that can be enabled/disabled directly in the `git diff` command.

Comment: Such an "application" would be the GNU `indent`, in the unlikely case that someone hasn't heard of it before ...