# Is there a good way to track changes in Excel sheets in GIT repo?

Tags: excel, git, vba, binaryfiles

I have tried the solutions provided in [How to perform better document version control on Excel files and SQL schema files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083502/how-to-perform-better-document-version-control-on-excel-files-and-sql-schema-fil/17106035#17106035), but I was unable to find a good solution for unzip the files to see the changes which can be tracked by Git. I have been using Git for a while and wanted to know if there is a good and fairly simple way to tracks the changes being made. Excel is being used in JAVA framework.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17083502/5784831) might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) with a little help of something like Python to automatically export your VBA code and track it with Git. For a detailed walk-through, see this [blog post](https://www.xltrail.com/blog/auto-export-vba-commit-hook).

Nowadays you can also use the open-source Git extension [Git XL](https://www.xltrail.com/git-xl) that allows you to see the diffs on the command line. It also integrates with Atlassian's free SourceTree tool, see this [blog post](https://dev.to/fzumstein/how-to-diff-excel-vba-code-in-sourcetree-git-client-36k) for a detailed walk through on how to set everything up.