# Version Control of Spreadsheet containing Decision Tables

Tags: excel, git, version-control, drools

We have used Drools for our business rules management .We have created decision tables in spreadsheets and use MS-Excel for it .
We use git as a version control system.We are a big team and are facing huge issues with merging our changes made to the decision table excel sheet .
We co-ordinate will all developers and make all the changes in one excel sheet and then check into GIT.

What is the most efficient way of handling and merging the decision tables spreadsheet into git ?
Any alternate solution which can make each developer in-dependently check in their changes made to the decision rules spreadsheet into git ?

Comment: Maybe this question (+ answers) can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083502/how-to-perform-better-document-version-control-on-excel-files-and-sql-schema-fil

Comment: Since excel is binary file, if you manage excel in git version control, you need to resolve the merge conflict manually. Or is it ok for you to merge the conflict files by keeping one side's version?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to version your decision tables in csv file that can be converted to xls.